# Spreadsheet populated with CFSPREADSHEET is not executing formulas automatically

Tags: excel, coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I have a single sheet spreadsheet with formulas already in it.

With CFSPREADSHEET, I populate the fields that the formulas reference and send the newly created spreadsheet to the user.

Once the new spreadsheet has been downloaded and opened (and enable editing clicked), the formulas do not execute.  The fields just stay blank.

Is there a way to get them to update automatically that I am missing?

Comment: Have you tried to go to the tab "Formulas" and click on the little triangle next to "Calculation options". There select "Automatic"?

Comment: @Wouter Yes, I've tried that.  Even clicking "Calculate Now" does not do anything. The only way I can get the formula to kick in is to actually change on of the referenced values.

Comment: I can't think of anything right now, do you have some more relevant information?

Comment: Are you still having this issue? I found this post with your same issue on the House of Fusion forums - http://www.houseoffusion.com/groups/cf-talk/thread.cfm/threadid:61484